# ldconfig issue with non-standard lib directory in CentOS

Tags: centos, compiling, path, libraries

I am working with a virtual machine (CentOS 5.3) that has very little storage space on the main drive (which includes `/usr`, `/usr/local`, etc). Most of the storage space is available on a separate drive that is mounted to `/mnt`. Consequently, on this drive I have created a basic installation directory (with subdirectories like `bin`, `include`, `lib`, etc) and installed a library there.

```
[standage@vm142-46 ~]$ ls -lhp /mnt/lib
total 33M
-rw-r--r-- 1 standage iplant-everyone 21M Dec 21 16:29 libgenometools.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 standage iplant-everyone 13M Dec 21 16:29 libgenometools.so
```

I then tried to link to that library with code that I had written, but it gave me the following message.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgenometools
```

I realized I had not updated `ldconfig` with the new installation directory I had created, so I went ahead and added `/mnt/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and ran `/sbin/ldconfig`. However, when I tried to link my code again I got the same error.

I was eventually able to get the libraries to link by creating symlinks to `/usr/local/lib64`...

```
[standage@vm142-46 ~]$ sudo ln -s /mnt/lib/libgenometools.a /usr/local/lib64
[standage@vm142-46 ~]$ sudo ln -s /mnt/lib/libgenometools.so /usr/local/lib64
```

...but this doesn't really solve my original problem, it's just a duct-tape solution. What did I do wrong originally and how can I link to the library I've installed?

Comment: Apart from that is was the wrong place to do it - "ld.so.conf" is also the wrong place to put your own path. use the directory "ld.so.conf.d" and create a *.conf file there. ld.so.conf is a file from the glibc library. If it ever gets updated you might run into trouble (although it is marked as config-file in the rpm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/etc/ld.so.conf` only influences the dynamic linker, i.e. where libraries are looked for at run time. When you build an executable, what matters is the paths where `ld` looks for the library. The usual way to specify these is to pass the `-L` option; most `configure` scripts have a way to pass additional `-L` options. There usually isn't a way to change the default search path for `ld`. You might look into changing the gcc spec file, but that will involve changing a file under `/usr`, not under `/etc`.

Given your slightly awkward setup, you may want to look into a [union mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount) of `/mnt` above `/usr`. I don't know what union mount possibilities CentOS offers if any (of course, there are third-party options, native or based on FUSE).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying regarding `/etc/ld.so.conf`. I've taught myself most of what I know about compiling, linking, makefiles, etc., and for some reason I thought `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `ldconfig` affect both compile-time and run-time behavior. I extended my makefile so that the user can provide additional `-L` flags, and this seems to be a good long-term solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ldconfig -v` to see, if ldconfig know about a new library. I pretend, that message `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgenometools` is during linking phase of compiling program, isn't it? Then you must say to linker, where it may find a library using a `-L/mnt/lib` parameter.